Target a Google sheet by its position
Is it possible to target a Google sheet by its position?
My script changes the title of the sheet to todays date so it's not a fixed title. The script also moves the position of the sheet to the left making it always the second sheet.
Can I target that sheet based on this known position?
Or can I target the sheet name based on todays date? I'm not sure of the syntax required to do this. The date format I'm using is for example '28 May - 2024'

with formula only try:
=INDIRECT(TEXT(TODAY(); "dd mmm - yyyy")&"!A1:C10")


to target sheet's position, you will need script:
function SHEET(input) {
try {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets() ;
  if( (input>0) && (input <= sheets.length)) return sheets[(input-1)].getName() ;
  else return "invalid sheet #" ;
}
catch( err ) {
  return "#ERROR!" 
}
}

then formula will be:
=INDIRECT(SHEET(2)&"!A1:C10")

